# SQL Server 2008 Merge Statement to check and insert if a record doesnt exist

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am trying to add a record into a table by checking against certain conditions for the existance of record through sql script. I am trying it using Merge Statement. Its not working couldnt tract out where i am going wrong. Can some one help me with this?. Thanks

```
MERGE Categories As target
    USING (
    SELECT CategoryKey 
    From Categories where CategoryName = 'TestName'
    ) AS source on (source.CategoryKey = target.CategoryKey)
WHEN Not Matched THEN
    INSERT VALUES ('TestName');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do the job:

```
MERGE Categories As target
USING (SELECT 'TestName' AS CategoryName) AS source 
    ON (source.CategoryName = target.CategoryName)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CategoryName) VALUES ('TestName');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AdaTheDev!! It really helped

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

I ask because you are using the same table as target and as source and since you are comparing the CategoryKey, which I assume is the primary key, the `WHEN Not Matched` condition will never be evaluated, because if you have a table with IDs 1, 2 and 3 and compare against itself where ID=ID, all rows will evaluate to true.

try to change `WHEN Not Matched THEN` to `WHEN Matched then UPDATE`  and write a simple test update sop you can see the behavior I'm talking about

EDIT
try this (assuming your ID is auto-increment)

```
MERGE Categories As target
    USING (
    SELECT CategoryKey 
    From Categories where CategoryName = 'TestName'
    ) AS source on (source.CategoryName = target.CategoryName)
WHEN Not Matched THEN
    INSERT VALUES ('TestName');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Diego. But i dont want to update the record, all i need to do is to check if a record with CategoryName as 'TestName' exists or not. If exists do nothing, else i want to add a record.

Comment: read my answer again. I said to run an update just so you can understand what's going on. The way you are writing your query you will never get a "WHEN Not Matched"